# The serve command required to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular7, angular-cli-v7

I downloaded [Angular Formio](https://github.com/formio/angular-formio) project. The project is in angular 6 version. I want to completely migrate this project into angular version 7 and use this features in my project which is on angular version 7. but before I need to run the project and access it on localhost, make some changes and test it.

I am getting the below error when I run ng serve from the command line:

```
The serve command required to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found
```

I am unable to fix it. Below are the steps that I have followed after downloading the project and to update my angular CLI

```
npm install
npm audit fix
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

I'm still facing the same issue.

[image: project structure]

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not an angular-cli project. It's built using gulp apparently. If you want to help upgrade the project to Angular 7, you should get in touch with its maintainers and ask them for help on getting started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `angular.json` is missing. The cli needs this file. To elaborate on this a bit more: The projects seems to not use the angular cli but gulp combined with npm tasks instead. Refer to the developer documentation of that project.

Comment: How can I get this file installed?

Comment: The projects seems to be written without the angular cli. You should use the flow provided in their developer guide (if they have one).

Comment: Yes they have provided the guide, it said 1) Make sure you have the Angular CLI installed on your machine. 2) Download the Angular Demo Application to your computer. 3) With your terminal, type npm install 4) Now type ng serve

Comment: The project you downloaded is not the demo but the library source code I guess?

Comment: The demo code is just a login/register form example, I want drag and drop filter ui using formio which I have alredy downloaded

Comment: Yes, but the explanation you postet was for the demo code, not for the library itself. To develop on the library, you have to get in contact with the developers or consult the documentation (if there is one) since the library itself was NOT build with angular-cli.